# Optimize an update SQL that runs on a Oracle table with 500M rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running following update query based on input from front end application. Since It is updating more than 550M rows, I've stopped it manually after executing it for 5 hrs. Entire code is big so I've posted below code for 2 fields. Could you please suggest what improvement can be done in this?

I've researched it extensively, e.g. `add pragma udf in function`, but I am hesitant to add PRAGMA UDF in it because these functions are being used in millions of other transformations/calculations in production environment inside PLSQL and I've read `PRAGMA UDF slows down if functions are being called from PL/SQL rather than SQL`.

**1)** Could you please suggest how I can add PRAGMA UDF in this block without making changes to original functions?

**2)** Should I add hints for the index in update statement? If yes, How I can add hints, such as index hints, in update block?

`P.S.: 1) Explain plan is from the test environment in which I've very few rows of data as compared to the production environment.2) other fields are using the same functions.`

```
--EXPLAIN PLAN

Plan hash value: 234644540

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                         |               |     1 |  2527 |   240   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE                                  | MORT_BACK_SEC |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                                  |               |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |               |     1 |  2498 |   240   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |               |   372 |  2498 |   240   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| RPT_ACCT_HIER |     1 |   491 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX2          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IDX4          |   372 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | MORT_BACK_SEC |     1 |  2007 |   238   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("RPT_ACCT_HIER"."ACCT_GEN2"='a1000')
   7 - access("D"."GL_ACCOUNT_ID"="RPT_ACCT_HIER"."ACCT_MEMBER")
   8 - filter("D"."AS_OF_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2019-06-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
   - 1 Sql Plan Directive used for this statement

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--CODE

IF id = 8 then
MERGE INTO(
SELECT A.*,
USB.BAS2_RWA_CALC (BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, NVL (IMP_CUR_BOOK_BAL, 0), NVL (BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, 0), .06, .08) AS V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA

--and 20 more function calls for 20 other fields 

FROM USB.MORT_BACK_SEC A) D

USING (SELECT * FROM USB.rpt_acct_hier) B
       ON (a.gl_account_id = b.acct_member and a.as_of_date = TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') and b.acct_gen2 = 'a1000')

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
IMP_BAS_EB_RWA = V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA,
IMP_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND (USB.BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL (TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA, 0), 2)
WHERE AS_OF_DATE = TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') --V_IMP_BAS_EB_RWA is being calculated above and then passed as input here

--20 more fields to be updated

end if;


--USB."BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL" function is being called for updating IMP_BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USB."BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL"
 (v_date in date, v_RWA in number,v_RWC in number) return number result_cache

 is

v_capital number(14,2);
v_rate number(15,8);

begin

v_rate := case when year(v_date) < 2010 then 0.06
          when year(v_date) >= 2010 and year(v_date) < 2012 then 0.07
          when year(v_date) = 2012 then 0.0775  
          when year(v_date) > 2012 and  year(v_date) < 2018 then 0.08        
else 0.085 end;


v_capital := (v_RWA + v_RWC) * v_rate;
return round(v_capital,2);

end;
/

--USB."BAS2_RWA_CALC" function which is inside MERGE into(...) block is as below


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USB."BAS2_RWA_CALC" 
(v_formula in char,v_bal in number,v_k_factor in number, v_bas_min in number,v_rwa_adj_rate in number) return number result_cache

 is

v_rwa number(15,2);

begin

v_rwa := nvl(v_bal,0)*nvl(v_k_factor,0)/nvl(v_bas_min,0);
v_rwa := v_rwa*(1+v_rwa_adj_rate);
return round(v_rwa,2);

end;
/
```

Comment: No indexes on either `MORT_BACK_SEC.AS_OF_DATE` or `RPT_ACCT_HIER.ACCT_GEN2`?  Judging from their named and the example data, they both look pretty selective (especially `AS_OF_DATE`).

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: at present there are no indexes. Since I am new to oracle and performance tuning, could you please suggest what index I should create and how I should integrate it using hints in this query?

Comment: Do you have a development environment where it is safe to try things?  If so, try creating the two I mentioned above.

Comment: I've created following indexes in DEV environment. ```CREATE INDEX USB.IDX2 ON USB.rpt_acct_hier(acct_gen2) ; CREATE INDEX USB.IDX1 ON USB.MORT_BACK_SEC (AS_OF_DATE)```. ```New explain plan is updated in question```. ```It is showing upgrade in RPT_ACCT_HIER but MORT_BACK_SEC is still going for full scan```

Comment: Sorry for another comment. Created ```CREATE INDEX USB.IDX4 ON usb.MORT_BACK_SEC
(gl_account_id)``` as well

Comment: Just creating an index does not help - you have to compute statistics on this index, otherwise the optimizer can't use the index: ALTER INDEX <index.name> COMPUTE STATISTICS.

Comment: I don't see the full scan in your updated explain plan.  Is it still running slowly?  You may have a performance problem in one of the 18 functions you _didn't_ post.  Also, btw, the two functions you did post could probably benefit a little bit by adding `DETERMINISTIC` (because they are) and also `PRAGMA UDF;`.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: They are same functions, calculated 20 other times for 20 other column updates. I'll add ```pragma udf``` but i was suspicious that it may degrade performance because they're being used in PL/SQL procs as well. I have read that PRAGMA UDF is useful when calling functions from SQL statements. Would you still suggest to add ```PRAGMA UDF```?  Also, full scan is gone because I've created index ```CREATE INDEX USB.IDX4 ON usb.MORT_BACK_SEC
(gl_account_id, as_of_date);```. However, nested loop has appeared now.

Comment: @TMS _you have to compute statistics on this index, otherwise the optimizer can't use the index_   .... that is not true.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Yes, you're right about that. Since 10g you don't need to compute statistics anymore... (https://community.oracle.com/thread/3591765). My oracle foo gets rusty :-)

Comment: To process a *large number of rows effectively* you shoud apprach two things. **get rid of `NESTED LOOPS`** - check for *updatable join view* (which will use a `HASH JOIN`). Additionaly you should get rid of the **function calls** (that cause a *context switch*). Rewrite the logic in SQL or use the *embedded PL/SQL* if you are on 12. I'm afraid there is no *missing index problem* in your scenario.

Comment: Additionally (read the execution plan notes) - check the `Sql Plan Directive` if it is usefull or should be deactivated. Check if you could use the *parallel option* meaningfully.

Comment: @SachinSharma the execution plan suggests it is dealing with 372 rows, not 500M. Are your stats up to date? Also I am not aware of any performance downside when calling `pragma pdf` functions in pure PL/SQL.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: This posted execution is a sample which mimics the same issue with less # of rows/data in the test table. I can't add ```PRAGMA UDF``` in production function because this function is being used in millions of other places and I've read, from multiple sources, that it downgrades performance if it is being used in PL/SQL block. One of the link is ```Link: http://oraclescan.blogspot.com/2016/07/pragma-udf-user-defined-functions-in.html```. please refer to ```limitations``` at the end.